# Rails - Generate subject field with URL helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, field, populate

I've just incorporated a messaging system on my Rails app. 
When a user replies to an existing message, I would like the subject field to populate with "Re: #{subject}" or something along those lines. Currently each message that is sent is just a form with a blank field for subject and body.

Here's what the code currently looks like:

```
<% @received.each do |a| %> 
Sent from <%= link_to User.find(a.sender_id).name, User.find(a.sender_id) %> 
<%= a.body %>
<%= link_to "Reply", new_user_message_path(user_id: current_user, instructor_id: User.find(a.sender_id)) %>
```

So in this case, the "Reply" link above should pass in the subject as parameters to the New Message form which is on a separate page. (If the subject is "painting", then the Reply link should be populated with the subject: "Re: painting") How do I achieve this?

Comment: Sidenote - do not pass current_user as param, that makes your app prone to attacks. Assing message author in create action in controller.

Comment: How does your form look?

Comment: Thanks Michael, I didn't know that about current_user.

Comment: My form looks like this: https://gist.github.com/jennojenno/5996312

Comment: In this form how can you tell in a message is a response or not?

Comment: You can't tell it is a response. I'm not quite sure how to implement that, so that's why my idea was to pass in the subject line from the Reply link in my original code... Is there a better way?

Comment: Ok, there may be one way to tell it's a response. In Reply link you could put additional variable like `response_for=_msg_id_` and in controllers new action check for that and itf it is set take old msg title and prefix it with Re: like `"Re: #{orig.title}"`